# Bad Request error while running php

Tags: php, apache, web-development-server

[image: Bad Request!]

I am getting a Bad Request error that I don't understand how to remove.
I have just started learning php and its a basic hello world program.can someone explain to me why this error is showing and how to remove it.I am using xampp for apache and brackets editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this without using port(default port is **80**):

```
http://localhost/PHPPractice/Example.php
```

You can use your projects by

```
c:/xampp/htdocs/
->helloworld/index.php
->helloworld/home.php
```

You can access it by

```
localhost/helloworld
localhost/helloworld/home.php
```

Here is the [Tutorialspoint Tutorial to use xampp easily.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/shorttutorials/run-a-php-program-in-xampp-server)

And you don't need any permissions to run your project folder.